# Ways to call a Javascript function using the value of a string variable?

Tags: javascript, function

I've seen this technique for calling a Javascript function based on the value of a string variable.

```
function foo() {
    alert('foo');
}

var test = 'foo';

window[test]();  //This calls foo()
```

Is this the accepted way to do it or is there a better way?  Any cross-browser issues to worry about?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Looks fine to me. I would probably create a simple helper function like following:

```
function runFunction(name, arguments)
{
    var fn = window[name];
    if(typeof fn !== 'function')
        return;

    fn.apply(window, arguments);
}

//If you have following function

function foo(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}

//You can call it like

runFunction('foo', ['test']); //alerts test.
```

Comment: +1, beat me to it and had a better caller function.

Comment: Good answer.  I think having a helper that does some sanity checking is a great idea.

Comment: How often would you call a function declared at the global scope and give it a context other than null? (btw I think your use of the word scope is misleading, context would be better)

Comment: I thought long and hard about it and you are right, there won't be a situation where I would need to pass scope to the global function, will modify the code.

Comment: Awesome function!. I modified the line (for my use) to have 'return fn.apply(window,arguments)' so that I can get a return as well.

Comment: Perhaps using `call` method. I tested and it seems that you can then parse more arguments. I tried: `fn.call(window, window, arguments);` which will create these arguments for the `foo` function: `[Window, Array[1]]`.
If you try the same with `apply` you will not gain access to all of the parameters.

Comment: The helper method should also receive context. It may not always be `window` context.

Answer (score 9):

I personally wouldn't bother even with a helper function

```
  window[someKey]('test')
```

would be fine.

However I wouldn't general maintain a set of possible functions to call at the global scope anyway.  Hence I would use a more general pattern:-

```
 obj[someKey]('test')
```

where obj may be `this`, a property of this or variable from a closure.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use it like this... (of course substitute the strings with variables where needed)

```
document["getElementById"]("elementName")["style"]["border"] = "1PX SOLID GREEN";
```

Which is also easily/usually typed like this of course...

```
document.getElementById("elementName").style.border = "1PX SOLID GREEN";
```

Here's another multi-dimensional example...

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject["myValue"]["one"] = "first value";
myObject["myValue"]["two"] = "second value";
alert(myObject["myValue"]["two"]); //outputs "second value"
```

Which could also be written as...

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject["myValue"] = {one: "first value", two: "second value"};
alert(myObject["myValue"]["two"]); //outputs "second value"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval(str)

```
eval('foo();');
```

use this with extreme caution.

Comment: -1. There is no need to use eval here.

Comment: Did I understand the question wrong? why is eval wrong?

Comment: Using eval you invoke the Javascript parser and goodness knows what else that is need to take text and turn it into a set of instructions that can be executed.  window['foo']() works so eval should be avoided in this case

Comment: Generally speaking, you should avoid using eval as it starts JS interpreter to execute code specified to eval. Additionally, user wants to execute a function given he has a name of the function in a string variable. Your code doesn't really do that.

Comment: Using eval is frowned upon in the JavaScript for good reason. But its also a valid answer to the question.

Comment: Avoid eval at all costs (think: eval is evil). -1 because OP already had an almost workable solution, and this suggestion is worse.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function to call a named function. It works both in browser and in Node.js. I have created a gist (https://gist.github.com/netsi1964/3f19bd96f2d6e18bd818) which also contains a small test. The fingerprint of the function is: `callFunction(scope, fn, args)`.
It sets the scope in the function to the specified scope, and defaults to `window` (in browser) and `global` (in Node.js).
To answer your original request you would use it like this:
`callFunction(window, "foo",["test"])`