# fire a function whose name is in a string

Tags: javascript, variables, function, autoload

I'd like to fire a function. Unfortunately I can't call it directly as the functions' name is provided as a string.

Example:

```
function myFunction() {
   alert('I am myFunction');
}
function anotherFunction() {
   alert('I am anotherFunction');
}

var func_name = 'myFunction';

$obj = jQuery('a');

$obj.each(function(){
   $(this).func_name(); // eval didn't help here :( 
});
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as JS expects func_name to be a valid function. Is there a way to have myFunction() fired instead of func_name()? Thanks.

UPDATE: Well, after testing some of the answers, it seems that my problem description isn't complete. :O I updated the code to include an object, which I want the function to be attached/run on.

Thanks again!

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496961/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-name-using-a-string

Comment: Dup again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/javascript-function-name-as-a-string/359910

Comment: And again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

Comment: And finally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144297/ways-to-call-a-javascript-function-using-the-value-of-a-string-variable

Comment: The best solution would almost certainly be to find a way not to have the function name in a string

Answer (score 7):

No reason to use eval. If your function is global, use `window[func_name]()`

With your updated question:

```
//the function $ returns an object, thus, this is changed
$(this).func_name();

//to this:
$(this)[func_name]();
```

Comment: Indeed. But I'll leave my answer, anyway. Just for the case it's not global ;-)

Comment: Good answer. In JavaScript, most things you can do with a dot operator, you can also do with bracket notation. so a.foo() and a['foo']() do the same thing. Stay away from eval() whenever you can.

Comment: so, just to make sure I get this right. the 'a' is an object? and 'foo' is the functions name here? Then my current jQuery(this).eval(function_name+'()'); becomes jQuery(this)[function_name](); right?

Comment: actually I don't get it to work. Seems I'm missing something... but what?

Greatly appreciated if someone might take a look at http://contactsheet.de/sandbox/autoload/index.html in comparison to
http://contactsheet.de/sandbox/autoload/index2.html (where I'm trying to fire the same plugin with the discussed method - right after the alert). Thank you so much!

Comment: As far as I can tell the problem seems to be that you're not giving the function correct arguments. Otherwise it looks correct.

Answer (score 2):

For methods, use

```
obj[func_name]()
```

Remember that globally declared functions are properties of the global object (ie `window` in browsers).

For local functions, as far as I know there's no way around

```
eval(func_name)()
```

Comment: For local, try this[func_name]();

Comment: `this` is not quite local, what he meant is `(function(){ function A(){}; eval('A')(); })();`

Answer (score 2):

As other have mentioned, this is done with **property accessor operators** - "[" and "]". What matters in this case is how this function is declared and **where it's being referenced from**.

If it is **declared globally** (i.e. in the global scope, as function declaration or function expression), or assigned to a property of a Global Object at some point, then it is possible to access it as a property of a Global Object. In 3rd. edition of ECMAScript-262, one can access Global Object with an expression such as:

```
(function(){ return this; })();
// or just `this` when in global scope
```

(Note that in browsers, Global Object is usually the same object as the one referenced by global `window`, although it doesn't have to be that way).

So you would access global function as:

```
var globalObj = (function(){ return this; })();
globalObj['your_func'];

// or via `window`
window['your_func'];
```

The problem usually arises when function is **declared locally** – that is in another function body:

```
(function(){
  function your_func(){};
  // how to access `your_func` here?
});
```

The problem is essentially due to the fact that while it is possible to access Global Object (as in previous example), **it's not possible to access function's Variable Object** (i.e. object used as a "base" for variable and function declaration in function code).

You can certainly use `eval` in cases like that but it's most definitely a wrong approach to the problem. A much easier, more compatible and runtime-efficient way is to **attach function as a property of some local object**:

```
(function(){
  ...
  function your_func(){}
  var funcs = { your_func: your_func };
  ...
})();
```

then **use the very same brackets** to access a property – property referencing function in question:

```
funcs['your_func'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval(func_name + "()");
```

Eval will take a string and evaluate it at runtime.

Comment: Explanations needed for point deductions.  This is a valid approach regardless of your personal opinions.