# Javascript - Refactoring if..else statements (ES6)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, design-patterns, refactoring, conditional-statements

I am trying to refactor if..else statements.

My code:

```
let condition = 'hi';

if(condition === 'hi'){
  commonFunction('hi');
  console.log('hi is called');

}else if(condition === 'bye'){
  commonFunction('bye');
  console.log('bye is called');

}else if(condition.includes('happy')){
  commonFunction('happy');
  console.log('happy is called');

}else if(condition === 'greeting'){
  commonFunction('greeting');
  console.log('greeting is called');

}
```

Refactored Code:

```
if(condition === 'hi'){
  hi();
}else if(condition === 'bye'){
  bye();
}else if(condition.includes('happy')){
  happy();
}else if(condition === 'greeting'){
  greeting();
}

function hi(){
  commonFunction('hi');
  console.log('hi is called');
}

function bye(){
  commonFunction('bye');
  console.log('bye is called');
}

function happy(){
  commonFunction('happy');
  console.log('happy is called');
}

function greeting(){
  commonFunction('greeting');
  console.log('greeting is called');
}
```

Is it better to declare each functions by condition like my refactored code???

Or, How about make class and call commonFunction by constructor?
(I think switch..case is not useful becasue I have a condition that has includes() )

Comment: @lucumt I have includes() in my condition so I think I can't use switch

Comment: this is really relative to how dynamic your functions will be. In your example, you could just declare 1 function and pass 2 parameters. Also you can call function by string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144334/10412708

Comment: In the above case, can't we do something like below?

const functionToCall = condtion.includes('hello') ? 'hello' : condtion;
component(functionToCall);

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use an *object* containing functions, rather than having multiple standalone functions. Then, just use property lookup.

For this exact code, though, you could make it even DRY-er by using a `Proxy` to check which property was accessed, rather than having multiple properties (because all of your properties/functions have common functionality):

```js
const condition = 'hi';

const fns = new Proxy({}, { get: (_, prop) => {
  console.log(prop + ' is called');
}});

const props = ['hi', 'bye', 'greeting'];
if (condition.includes('happy')) {
  fns.happy();
} else if (fns[condition]) {
  fns[condition]();
}
```

This is extremely DRY, but pretty odd to do - in most situations, you'd use an object instead:

```js
const fns = {
  hi() {
    console.log('hi is called');
  },
  bye() {
    console.log('bye is called');
  },
  greeting() {
    console.log('greeting is called');
  },
  happy() {
    console.log('happy is called');
  }
}

const condition = 'hi';

if (condition in fns) {
  fns[condition]();
} else if (condition.includes('happy')) {
  fns.happy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to move all these `if-else`s into `commonFunction` itself (if it does not contain the same `if-else`s again, if it does you need more complex refactoring):

```js
const commonFunction = (condition) => {
  let f = ['hi', 'bye', 'happy', 'greeting'].find(e => condition.includes(e))
  console.log(f + ' is called');
  if (!f) return;
  // do something
  // return the result if needed
}

commonFunction('greeting')
commonFunction('die')
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing can do about that is declare the function in an `object` using the `condition` as `keys`.

```
let objFunc = {
    'hi': function() {
       commonFunction('hi');
       console.log('hi is called');
    },
    'happy': function() {
       commonFunction('happy');
       console.log('happy is called');
    },
    'bye': function() {
       commonFunction('bye');
       console.log('bye is called');
    },
    'greeting': function() {
       commonFunction('greeting');
       console.log('greeting is called');
    },
};


objFunc[condition]();
```

Comment: However, I have condition that using includes()... How can I using the condition as keys in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In your original code you have written multiple if else statement just to call same function with different pre-defined argument, so instead of refactoring by your way,
i think this is much easier and small code.

```
let predefinedArgs = {
    hi: 'hi',
    bye: 'bye'
    ...
}

let condition = 'hi'
commonFunction(predefinedArgs[`condition`]);
```

Comment: However, I have condition that using includes()... How can I using the condition as keys in this situation?

Comment: You have condition that using includes() means what please tell me, i am not getting question ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a set of conditions for which you want to call a common function. The best way to do this is simply test whether you can handle the condition (that's where you can use `includes`). Then call that function.

```js
const allowed = ['hi', 'bye', 'happy', 'greeting']

let condition = 'happy'

if (allowed.includes(condition)) {           // do you know how to deal with condition? 
  commonFunction(condition)                 // if so call the function
} else {
  console.log(`unknown condition ${condition}`) // otherwise log an error
}

// not sure what commonFunction does, so this is just for the example
function commonFunction(condition) {
  console.log(`${condition} is called`);
}
```

Comment: `happy` differs from the others: `else if(condition.includes('happy'))`

Answer (score 0):

I think all the solutions should work fine. In respect of the condition which has includes, maybe you can try to add in a new parameter.
What I meant was, as stated in earlier answers:

````
  let f = ['hi', 'bye', 'happy', 'greeting'].find(e => condition.includes(e))
  console.log(f + ' is called');
  if (!f) return;
  // do something
  // return the result if needed
}

commonFunction('greeting')
commonFunction('die')```

This could be converted to :
```const commonFunction = (condition, functionName) => {
// ... other code
// and then use can use the following link to call the function which you want to execute`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492013/javascript-refactoring-if-else-statements-es6/53492079
const young = () => {//...}
and the calling could be:
commonFunction('greeting', slice)
commonFunction('die', young)```

Hope this makes sense!
````