# Call Javascript object/function from value of a string variable

Tags: javascript

I'm running an event listener on an object like below

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotOnload', (event) => {
    // do something
});
```

What I'm looking for is load `googletag.pubads()` via a variable value, and then the event listener should be applied on the `variable`. For eg:-

```
var x = 'googletag.pubads';

x().addEventListener('slotOnload', (event) => {
    // do something
});
```

Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144297/ways-to-call-a-javascript-function-using-the-value-of-a-string-variable), This is what I tried

```
function runFunction(name, arguments)
{
    var fn = window[name];
    if(typeof fn !== 'function')
        return;

    fn.apply(window, arguments);
}


var x = runFunction('googletag.pubads', [])  // this returns undefined
```

For the uninitiated, `googletag` is a package that shows ads on your page. Stackoverflow also uses `googletag` for displaying the ads. You may try the `eventListener` on Stackoverflow page console itself.

How can I fix this?? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You would lookup `window['googletag']`, and in THAT object lookup the `pubads` member.

Comment: Why? Specifically, where are you getting this string and what are its possible values? Matters in order to not complicate the solution unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `x` string to an actual object reference by parsing it:

```js
// Helper function: simple parser
const getAtPath = (root, path) => path.split(".").reduce((obj, k) => obj[k], root);

// Mock for demo:
var googletag = { pubads: { addEventListener(typ, cb) { cb(); } } };

// Demo
var x = 'googletag.pubads';
getAtPath(window, x).addEventListener("", () => console.log("addEventListener called"));
```

This snippet just uses a very basic parser: it assumes that the input is a dot-separated list of property names.

If the dynamic name would use more extended syntax, for instance to reference array indexes with bracket notation, ...etc, then the parser needs to foresee that. See also [lodash `_.get`](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/get/)